# Angular "HTTP Failure during parsing for ..." error

Tags: angular

I've been trying to learn to deploy a MEAN app, I've used the **ng build** command, and the app seems to be loading fine, except in places where I have to retrieve data from the database(I'm using mlab), it's showing this error instead:

> message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/tickets  /ticketList"

Here's my code:

**ticket-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ UserService } from '../user.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ticket-list',
  templateUrl: './ticket-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ticket-list.component.css']
})
export class TicketListComponent implements OnInit {
li:any;

  constructor(private test:UserService) { }

del(x){
  console.log(x);
  this.test.deleteTicket(x);
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.test.getTicketList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.li = data;
    })
  }

}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { stringify } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getTicketList(){

   return this.http.get("tickets/ticketList", {responseType: 'text'});

    }
}
```

**the html file**

```
<div class="ticketList">
<table>
  <th>Event Name</th>
  <th>Title</th>

  <tr *ngFor="let d of li; let i = index">
    <td>{{d.eventName}}</td>
    <td>{{d.title}}</td>
    <td class="view"><a routerLink="/extendedList" routerlinkActive="active">view</a></td>
    <td class="delete"><a (click)="del(d.eventName)"> delete</a></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you don't set the responseType in your get call and what is the response of your server?

Comment: It seems there's problem in your mongodb cloud service.. just call http://localhost:8080/tickets/ticketList from postman get request, & see if you're getting correct response

Comment: @rainerhahnekamp I get the same error, even after removing the response type.

Comment: @Shantanu I get an HTML file as a response, which seems to be the root html file

Comment: @geteds Then it's not the mlab service give the correct url of your REST service (database url hosted on mlab)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
getTicketList(){
  return this.http.get("tickets/ticketList", this.setHttpHeader());
}

setHttpHeader() {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json').set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let options = { headers: headers};
  return options;
}
```

Needless to say: **With HttpClientModule** we don't need to parse data after receiving; It will be done automatically.